# Как очистить пустые папки и файлы

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Не получается очистить папки не имеющие файлов (пустые) и файлы не имеющие размера.
Пробую так:

---

```
static string str1 = Path.GetTempPath();

public static void EmptyDirFiles()
{
  string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(str1, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  for (int i = dirs.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if (Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dirs[i]).Length == 0)
        Directory.Delete(dirs[i]);
  }
}
```

Но не удаляет, и лучше ли будет заменить `GetDirectories` на `EnumerateDirectories` ?

**[Обновление]** Изменил код:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(str1, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
for (int i = dirs.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dirs[i]).Count() == 0)
       Directory.Delete(dirs[i]);
}
```

Отчищает только папки, как очистить файлы пустые?

**[Обновил ответ по просьбе: Sv__t]**

```
string[] dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(str1, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(str1);
for (int i = dirs.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dirs[i]).Count() == 0)
       Directory.Delete(dirs[i], true);
}
foreach (string pathToFile in Directory.GetFiles(str1))
{
   if (new FileInfo(pathToFile).Length == 0)
           File.Delete(pathToFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление пустых файлов можно сделать так:

```
// Directory.GetFiles(str1) возвращает все пути к файлам в указанной директории
foreach(string pathToFile in Directory.GetFiles(str1))
{
     // здесь получаем размер файла и проверяем его
     if (new FileInfo(pathToFile).Length == 0)
     {
          try
          {
              File.Delete(pathToFile);
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
             // обработка исключения
          }
     } 
}
```

**Update**

Если с использованием тасков, то

для директорий:

```
        IEnumerable<String> dir = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(str1).
           Where(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).EnumerateFiles().Count() == 0);
        foreach (var d in dir)
        {
            new Task(() => Directory.Delete(d)).Start();
        }
```

для файлов:

```
        IEnumerable<String> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(str1).
           Where(y => new FileInfo(y).Length == 0);
        foreach(var f in files)
        {
            new Task(() => File.Delete(f)).Start();
        }
```

Comment: Вообще, код рабочий. Выложи, как теперь у тебя код выглядит?

Comment: Добавил try - catch. Возможно, какой-то файл занят процессом и программа на этом месте падает (попробовал, у меня сейчас так и было)

Comment: создай коллекцию строк, в эти строки при поиске загоняешь все найденные пустые файлы/папки. Далее прогоняешь в цикле коллекцию, загоняя в каждой итерации отдельный поток, пролетит мигом

Comment: @Sv__t, Спасибо за таски, А с папками так же можно? Интересно а почему `Directory.GetFiles(`), а не `Directory.EnumerateFiles` ?

Comment: Да, тут пожалуй лучше Enumerate использовать.